# Less : find the function to get a color X from color Y

Tags: css, less

I have 2 colors : color X and color Y.
Is there a script or rules to find the right function to get color Y from color X ?
ex : color_Y = darken(@color_X, 10%), i have color values, i just want to find the less function

Comment: Hello adokara, have you found a solution to your problem? I'm currently struggling with the same thing....

Comment: no i did 'nt find a solution... let me know if you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

It's basic math since that's what LESS is based on. Given that `color_Y` is 10% darker than `color_X`, it makes sense that `color_X` is 10% lighter than `color_Y`.

`color_X = lighten(@color_Y, 10%)`